# Wrap Text Around a Button

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create a box on a page which is mainly text with a small image at top-left and a button at bottom-right. Wrapping around the image is fine (I've done that dozens of times over the years) but placing the button seems to have beaten me. Whatever I do it always places itself below the text.

```css
.profile-container {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 4em);
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2c687b
}

.profile img {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 1em
}

.profile h2 {
  font-family: 'Neuropol', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  transform: scale(1, 1.3);
  margin-bottom: .5em
}

form {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1em
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="images/paul.jpg" alt="alt" />
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie diam consectetur suscipit tincidunt. Fusce ipsum mauris, bibendum nec massa sed, sodales mollis lacus. Sed dignissim semper neque in semper.</p>
    <p>Praesent lobortis tellus quis eros mollis congue. Nunc vel turpis vel enim vehicula commodo. Duis lectus ante, viverra ut lacinia ac, varius a nunc. Vivamus odio dui, pellentesque faucibus odio et, placerat convallis leo.</p>
    <p>Curabitur et tellus vitae massa tincidunt luctus. Fusce lacus nunc, facilisis id lobortis at, lobortis sed ante. Morbi sagittis eget nisl a lobortis. Donec interdum scelerisque erat ut blandit.</p>
    <form action="reviews.php" method="post" name="reviews">
      <input name="hiddenname" type="hidden" value="hiddenvalue">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="My Reviews">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yd5v7zrf/

It seems as though the form is always positioned according to its top edge, but I need to position it according to its bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a collapsed margin issue. Just add `display: inline-block;` to `.profile`.

```css
.profile-container {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 4em);
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2c687b
}

.profile {
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile img {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 1em
}

.profile h2 {
  font-family: 'Neuropol', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  transform: scale(1, 1.3);
  margin-bottom: .5em
}

form {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1em
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="images/paul.jpg" alt="alt" />
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie diam consectetur suscipit tincidunt. Fusce ipsum mauris, bibendum nec massa sed, sodales mollis lacus. Sed dignissim semper neque in semper.</p>
    <p>Praesent lobortis tellus quis eros mollis congue. Nunc vel turpis vel enim vehicula commodo. Duis lectus ante, viverra ut lacinia ac, varius a nunc. Vivamus odio dui, pellentesque faucibus odio et, placerat convallis leo.</p>
    <p>Curabitur et tellus vitae massa tincidunt luctus. Fusce lacus nunc, facilisis id lobortis at, lobortis sed ante. Morbi sagittis eget nisl a lobortis. Donec interdum scelerisque erat ut blandit.</p>
    <form action="reviews.php" method="post" name="reviews">
      <input name="hiddenname" type="hidden" value="hiddenvalue">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="My Reviews">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last paragraph to a span: https://jsfiddle.net/57a6gwyk/

```
<span></span>
<form style="float:right"></form>
```

Or just make the paragraph display:inline;

In response to the comment:

How about if you move the form up above the paragraph, and otherwise leave it as you had it:

https://jsfiddle.net/oq9pu3vy/

Comment: You know, Stack Snippets has a convenient feature where you can click "Copy snippet to answer", and the snippet shows up in the answer box. Then you can edit the snippet right there and the user gets to see your idea illustrated with their code.

Comment: That partly works. The trouble is that on the real page the last para is only one line long but the button is about three lines tall so it still hangs out the bottom. Even when I artificially lengthen the para, the button only overlaps the last line and the rest still hangs out the bottom.

Comment: Edited with a new fiddle.